# What is the standard featured image size?

Tags: posts, themes, post-thumbnails

Is there a standard featured image size that Wordpress works best with? Or is the featured image sizing based on theme settings or requirements?

Comment: Form follows function. Size should be dependent on your requirements. But in general use responsive images so the size is determined by the users screen size. Smaller resolutions should use smaller images. The sizes you supply will be influenced by your target devices.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress has a few [default sizes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail#Thumbnail_Sizes):

- Thumbnail ( Defaults to 150x150 )
- Medium ( Defaults to 300x300 )
- Large ( Defaults to 1024x1024 )
- Full ( Defaults to Original Image Size )

Of course, these can all be changed by visiting the `Settings -> Media` page in the Admin Panel of your installation. That being said, most the time Themes have their own sizes set for things such as Featured Images. You may want to either contact the theme author via the [WordPress support forums](https://wordpress.org/support/), which each theme has their own set of forums, or if it's a premium theme you should contact their support.

If none of these works just upload a featured image and copy the size that the theme generates, that will always give you your width and height needed.

Comment: Wait. I've been using Wordpress for years and I'm unfamiliar with your suggestion to "just upload a featured image and copy the size that the theme generates" as an option? Could you direct me to the proper steps to do this? Didn't think I'd come across as a newb but now I'm doubting my Wordpress skills lol...

Comment: @randomblink I mean to say, if you upload a featured image and view the post on the front-end your theme will generate the proper sizes ( assuming it's a competent theme ). From there you could just use View Source ( built into every browser, shortcut `CTRL + U` ) or browser [Developer Tools](http://devtoolsecrets.com/) to find the `width` and `height` attributes on the image. Usually there's no "one size fits all" for every theme out there because every theme has a different purpose. You have to go through a bit of trial and error to find the exact dimensions if it's not given by the theme.

Comment: Oh... I was envisioning some button or link that I had to click that had somehow escape my notice... lol.

Answer (score 0):

The default Feature image size in wordpress is 768px width (is a hiden image size that use to be use by themes)

The limitations of the image size are your theme (you must not have a different image size as the frame of your image in the post).

But if you are a developer and you would like to modify the image size. Those are the recomendations in articles if you would like to be featured in [google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article#non-amp).

- non-AMP webpages: google require a minimum of 696px wide
- AMP webpages: 1200px wide.